# php xml response gave me this after android sax parsing: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Tags: php, xml, android, parsing

i need to parse this php xml response in android:

```
<?phpxml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<SmsResponse>

<version>1</version>    
<result>0</result> 
<resultstring>failure</resultstring> 
<description>error</description>    
<endcause></endcause>
</SmsResponse>
```

Comment: try opening your xml document with `<?xml` instead of `<?phpxml`

Comment: What do you mean by "in android" ? Either it's PHP or another language (Java?), Android is just a platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error comes from the C expat XML parsing library, and it's telling you that XML files need to start "<?xml". if the server sending the bad response is yours, fix the server. if it isn't, you'll have to do something like responseString.replaceFirst("^<\\?phpxml", "<?xml") to fix it before handing it over to the XML parser.

this isn't Android-specific. all XML parsers should reject this invalid input.

Comment: Is there a way to make Java SAX Parser ignore this error, when you don't have ability to change the xml file?